# fastest way to grep jar file for a particular name in it?

Tags: grep, find

I am trying to find all the jars which has `spring` in its name. I am working with windows and using cygwin to run the linux commands. Does my below command looks right?

```
find . -name "*.jar" -exec jar tf '{}' \| grep -H "spring" \;
```

For some reason, it is still processing and haven't got the result on the screen. Any fast way to grep the jar file with a particular name?

For example, below are the valid jar files which has spring in it -

```
spring-web.jar
spring-core.jar
test-spring.jar
```

Comment: You can try without `grep` like this. `find /some/dir -type f -name "*spring*.jar"`

Comment: @Ramesh, OP's looking to check the jar listing for `spring`

Comment: @1_CR, yeah, so my command is also to search all `jar` files which has the word `spring` in it.

Comment: Your command is looking for a file name with spring in it, but it is looking at the files in the jar.

Comment: @richar: no only the jar name which has spring in its name.

Comment: @Webby: yes, I commented about what the command **does** do, not what is is supposed to do. I commented because it does **not** do what you say it does. Your command does: `for all files where there name ends in `.jar`, extract the name of the files in the jar, showing only those (in the jar) that have the word spring in the name.`

Answer (score 4):

I do not believe the `jar` command accepts multiple `.jar` files by way of arguments so AFAIK a single `jar` invocation addressing all `.jar` files is out of the question. One option to speed things up by avoiding one `find` exec invocation for each `.jar` file is the follows

```
find . -name '*.jar' -exec sh -c \
'for f; do  jar -tf "$f" | grep --label="$f" "spring"; done' sh {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

The below command would look for the jar files that have substring `spring` in it.

```
find /some/dir -type f -name "*spring*.jar"
```

Now, your original command looks through the content, which isn't what the text around it or the examples say.

```
find . -name "*.jar" -exec jar tf '{}' \| grep -H "spring" \;
```

Please find [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/conversation/transcript-of-message) chat description where Gilles explains why the above command is not what you are looking for.

**Testing**

```
[root@keithpc check]# cd jar_check/
[root@keithpc jar_check]# ls
[root@keithpc jar_check]# touch spring1.jar
[root@keithpc jar_check]# touch 1spring.jar
[root@keithpc jar_check]# touch no_sss_spring.jar
[root@keithpc jar_check]# touch spring.txt
```

**Output**:

```
[root@keithpc jar_check]# find ./ -type f -name "*spring*.jar"
./no_sss_spring.jar
./1spring.jar
./spring1.jar
```

As you can see, the `spring.txt` file is not returned which I believe is what you are looking for.

Now, to understand what your command does,

1. First I have created a java file which has the name as `springtest`.
2. Now, I create the `class` file by running the `java` command on the
   `java` file.
3. Now, I add it to the jar file by running the jar command.
4. Now, when I run your command, it will return me the `class` file
   rather than the jar file that you are looking for.

   ```
    [root@keithpc jar_check1]# javac springtest.java
    [root@keithpc jar_check1]# java springtest
    Hello,spring
    [root@keithpc jar_check1]# jar cvf springtest.jar springtest.class
    added manifest
    adding: springtest.class(in = 426) (out= 286)(deflated 32%)

    ##Here I run your command after creating the jar file. 

    [root@keithpc jar_check1]# find . -name "*.jar" -exec jar tf '{}' \| 
    grep -H "spring" \;
    ##As you can see, it returns me the class file rather than the 
    jar file as the output.  

    springtest.class
   ```